# Maven archetype's settings

Tags: maven, archetypes

I know how find out existing archetypes, mvn archetype:generate
But I dont't know how I can print settings, structure of folders of existing maven archetypes?

I try to read documentation and googling.
I'm expecting a command or script in command line.